# Kill a mysql "add columns" when the process doesn't show up in processlist

Tags: mysql, process, kill-process

I tried to insert a lot of columns (70) to a table that contains a lot of rows (1.5 million) and it is taking forever.
I'd like to stop it without damaging the data.
I read somewhere that I would need to run

```
show processlist
```

to find the process and then kill it.
But when I do that I can only see one process and it is not the one I want to kill.

Does that mean it is not actually running? Or is there something else I should be doing? Any ideas?

Comment: If it's running it's in that list. If it's not in that list maybe you're inadvertently running the query on a different server instance?

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure what you mean by that. I am doing this from phpMyAdmin. I added the columns with the built-in "add columns" feature and it now it simply says: "Loading...". I then opened a new tab in my browser, logged in to phpMyAdmin, opened the table and SQL tab, where I typed "show processlist".

Comment: What I mean is if that query is running then it will show up in the process list. If it's not running, or it's running on a different server, it won't. Make sure you're connected to the same server, as you might be looking in the wrong place, or it may have already finished.

Comment: @spencer7593 I am using the same user that added the columns.

Comment: If you're connected as the same user, to the same database instance, and you only see one process in the list, then the other session has been terminated. The session running the SHOW PROCESSLIST statement will be in the return. If there's only one session returned, there aren't any other sessions from the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an unprivileged user, `SHOW PROCESSLIST` only shows sessions for the user that you are connected as.

Connect to MySQL Server as the *same* user that is running the process you want to see.

Or, connect as a privileged user. For example, `'root'@'localhost'`, or any user that is granted `PROCESS` privilege. Then `SHOW PROCESSLIST` will show sessions for all users.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html

---

If `SHOW PROCESSLIST` only returns one row, that one row represents the session that's running the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` statement. Getting one row back means there are not other sessions from the same user. So that means that any other connections from the same user have been terminated.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer as it is informative and seems to be correct. After waiting for well over an hour I got two errors (undefined index).
Seems the data is unharmed. Thanks!